# What do you call this device that floats in the water at ports?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, image-identification

I've seen lots of these, at ports, floating on the water:

[image]

[image]

I don't have a clue about what they are called.

Comment: On the basis of the top answer on a [relevant Meta question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3119) I'm reopening this question. It's not obvious how to look up something if you don't know what it's called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**light(ed) buoy**

[Images of lighted buoys](https://www.google.com/search?q=lighted%20buoy&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911&sxsrf=AOaemvJdSYxXL7PMR8TK1tLg_lDLTyA0Ew:1634898301623&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwin8Ivk5t3zAhUUhXIEHV_aD3kQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=946&bih=468&dpr=1.5)

> **lighted buoy**
> Floating object used as beacon. [Visual Dictionary illustration](https://infovisual.info/en/transport/lighted-buoy)

> **light buoy**
>
> (Nautical) A buoy with a light on top which is lit at night to aid
> navigation. [Wiki](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/light_buoy)

**buoy**

> A floating device that can have many purposes. It can be anchored
> (stationary) or allowed to drift with ocean currents. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoy)

Comment: And the bird resting atop of it is a gull.  Buoys and gulls.

Comment: Encores aweigh!

Comment: The pronunciation can be tricky. _Buoy_ has two syllables /bui/, but /ui/ is not a common diphthong in English and /bui/ becomes /boy/ very easily. There are any number of jokes that trade on this confusion.

Comment: @JohnLawler Which is probably why M-W has  \ˈbü-ē , ˈbȯi \ for *buoy*. It gives \ˈbȯi-ənt, ˈbü-yənt\ for *buoyant* and similar for *buoyancy*, but I can't remember ever hearing these two with \bü\.

Comment: OED has Brit. /bɔɪ/, /bwɔɪ/, U.S./ˈbui/, /bɔɪ/

Comment: @JohnLawler - It has two syllables in American English. In Australian and British English it sounds much like "boy".

Comment: @nnnnnn - it always takes me aback when hearing audiobooks read by Americans, when they say 'boo-ee'. Also Brits would probably re-phrase 'he likes buoys' when discussing a sailor.